# Why my windows Variables doesn't show information, when i run debugger?

Tags: spring-boot, eclipse, debugging

I have Spring boot application, that have many layers, dao, controller, repository and e.t.c..
I put breakpoint in my controller class, in controller method that must return value in JSON.

```
 return gradebook.getStudents();
```

than i choose main class, and `Debug as-> Java application`, my thread is loading and running, also application started in console, but i can not see information in window Variables. I check in controller breakpoint stands on return, everything ok!

[image]

What i do to solve this problem, i choose window- Perspective -> reset Perspective.
Also i reloaded eclipse. But nothing change!

Comment: None of the threads in your image are paused, so it has no stack frame from which to show variables. Are you calling your intended method properly?

Comment: You only get that information when you hit a breakpoint or similar.

Comment: And what i must to do? I put this breakpoint on my controller method, than i go to main class and Debug As -> Java Application, and than thread running.
My controller have some problem, how i can solve that? i don't understand